# Vim - How can I install this simple markdown preview plugin with Pathogen?

Tags: vim, markdown, pathogen

I found a little plugin to help me preview markdown files from Vim.  It will let me see the HTML file in my default browser.  You can read about the plugin here: http://blog.natesilva.com/post/5256838248/how-to-preview-a-markdown-document-in-vim

The installation instructions say:

```
To install: Place markdown.vim in ~/.vim/ftplugin or " %USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\ftplugin.
```

However, I am using Tim Pope's `Pathogen` plugin-loading system to load several other plugins that are stored in their own directories under the bundle directory.  Can I do the same with this one? I tried creating a `bundle/markdown-preview/` directory and placing `markdown.vim` in it, but I wasn't able to get it to work that way.  What do I not understand?  Is it even necessary to use Pathogen in this case?  What problem will it solve for me?

Also, just to see if the plugin worked, I installed it in the ftplugin directory, as suggested.  Now, when I press `,p` Vim stops itself and the preview file is opened in my browser.  I get the message:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vim ./.dotfiles/vim/bundle/fugitive/README.markdown
```

How do I resume Vim and go back to editing the file once I've seen my preview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried creating a bundle/markdown-preview/ directory and placing markdown.vim in it, but I wasn't able to get it to work that way.

You should have tried putting it into `bundle/markdown-preview/ftplugin`, not where you claim you have tried to put it. There may still be some things that prevent it from working from this location.

For second question: follow [this](https://gist.github.com/960015#gistcomment-561405) comment and add `:redraw!` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks.  Any ideas on how I can return to Vim after previewing?

Comment: Also, I got it to work by substituting `bundle/markdown-preview/plugin/` where you had `bundle/markdown-preview/ftplugin/`.  Any ideas on when one uses `ftplugin` vs `plugin`?

Comment: @JonCrowell From ftplugin directory it is loaded each time you open markdown file (really each time you do `set filetype=markdown`). From plugin directory it gets loaded once when you open vim no matter what file type current file has. For most plugins that mean they are applied to one buffer only, any subsequently opened buffers do not benefit from wrongly positioned filetype plugin.

Comment: @JonCrowell For this particular plugin it makes sense to ignore the recommendation and put it into `plugin/` directory because author does not know how plugins, especially filetype ones, are to be written for vim (at least two issues: wrong escaping and wrong mapping command). The latter should have had string `<buffer>` as its first argument if it was really filetype plugin, but in any case `nnoremap` instead of `map`.

Comment: @JonCrowell By the way, I don’t see much sense in using pathogen in this case. It is convenient only when you want to use git repository of the plugin hence using `mkdir bundle/markdown-preview && git clone git://gist.github.com/960015 bundle/markdown-preview/ftplugin` in this case.

Comment: @JonCrowell Maybe better `git clone gist.github.com/960015 bundle/markdown-preview && mkdir bundle/markdown-preview/ftplugin && ln -s bundle/markdown-preview/{*.vim,}`: in this case repository is located so that you can do `for dir in bundle/* ; do test -d $dir/.git && (cd $dir && git pull) ; done` to update all git plugins.

Answer (score 0):

To get Pathogen to find the plugin I put the `markdown.vim` file in `bundle/markdown-preview/plugin/`.  This link helped me: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1711760